# Deploy multiple spring framework enabled web project and conflict

Tags: spring, tomcat, deployment

I have multiple Spring Framework enabled projects and try to deploy them into Tomcat.

If I deploy any single one, everything fine.

But if I deploy more than one projects, the deployment will fail from the second one.

Not sure if it caused by Spring or Tomcat. The error info related the Spring framework initialization.

Hope to know if it is a popular one.

Thanks in advance.

Log:

Nov 16, 2017 3:09:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart
Severe: Error starting static Resources
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid or unreadable WAR file : error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.naming.resources.WARDirContext.setDocBase(WARDirContext.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5247)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5436)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Nov 16, 2017 3:09:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
Severe: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/wshermesadminweb]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error in resourceStart()
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5437)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 10 more

Nov 16, 2017 3:09:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
Severe: Error deploying web application archive C:\Users\chenhang.AUTH\Documents\Tools\apache-tomcat-7.0.77\webapps\wshermesadminweb.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].Standar
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:903)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1984)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: There isn’t enough information here to enable anyone to help you.

Comment: Add the error log in tomcat: